Why shortcut key in Dbeaver act as right click?
I'm using DBeaver community in MacOS (sequoia)
When executing the query I try to use shortcut ctrl + return, insted of executing query dbeaver show me right menu click

When I click execute using mouse, dbeaver showing me another popup menu for closing tab

Is the shortcut is conflicted with MacOS right click?

Bug was fixed in the new release
‘Cmd+Enter’ shortcut was added in addition to ‘Ctrl+Enter’ on macOS due to the conflict with new system hot keys in Sequoia
https://dbeaver.io/2024/10/06/dbeaver-24-2-2/
